# Problems with layout & z-index

Tags: html, css

I was hopeing that you could help me out as I am new to HTML & CSS.

Trying to build a game interface.

What I am attemptin to do I thought would be simple:-

Tile a background img z-index -1
runner img Centre & repeat - x z-index 0
Container div to subdivide with divs to make my design layout would be z-index 1

But I cannot seem to get past stage 1.

I am hoping someone can point me as to where I am going wrong.

I am using dreamweaver cs6

This is what I thought would work:-

````
```
```
<title>Another Failed Attempt</title>
<style type="text/css">
#space {
    background-color: #000;
    background-image: url(interface/star_bg.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}
#space #runner img {
   background-color: #003;
   background-image: url(interface/runner_bg.jpg);
   background-repeat: repeat-x;
   background-position: center;
   z-index: 0;
   left: auto;
   right: auto;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="background" id="space"><img src="interface/star_bg.jpg" width="1024" height="1024" />
<div class="runner" id="runner"><img src="interface/runner_bg.jpg" width="568" height="564" /></div>
</div>
```
```
````

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it seems like you’re trying to create a game interface with HTML and CSS. Here are a few suggestions that might help you:

1. It's better to set the background image in the CSS than using `img` tag in the `div`.
2. The `z-index` property only works on positioned elements (position: absolute, position: relative, position: fixed, or position: sticky). In your code, you’ve correctly set the position of `#space` to relative, but not for `#runner`.
3. You’re using `#space #runner img` to select the runner image. This means you’re looking for an element with the ID `runner` inside an element with the ID `space`. However, in your HTML, `runner` is not nested inside `space`.

I've made some minor modifications, for your code

```
<title>Another Successful Attempt</title>
<style type="text/css">
#space {
    background-color: #000;
    background-image: url('interface/star_bg.jpg');
    background-repeat: repeat;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}
#runner {
   background-color: #003;
   background-image: url('interface/runner_bg.jpg');
   background-repeat: repeat-x;
   background-position: center;
   position: relative; /* Add this line */
   z-index: 0;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="space"></div>
<div id="runner"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: I get a nice white page :(

Comment: Check if you already access the file correctly or not. I think in this case, your website cannot load 'interface/runner_bg.jpg'.